# How to Unique and Sort values from a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has the same keys, but potentially different values per key. How do I get a list of unique values that are sorted alphabetically? Assume each value is a string.

Is there a better way than looping through each dictionary, adding each value to a list, sorting that list, and then removing non-unique values?

Comment: A simplified example of what you're starting with and what you'd like to get to would be helpful

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `tuple(sorted(the_dict.values()))` ?

Comment: Instead of *"..adding each value to a list, sorting that list, and then removing non-unique values"* you could add them to a set, convert to list and sort.

Comment: @T.Nel No. OP has multiple dictionaries with multiple keys.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, I'm just trying to understand, in my proposition the_dict.values() should be the values of every dict. But does the keys matter here? Or does he want a similar result? I probably missunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how simple it can be, but using *groupby* and and *set* this can be shorter (python 2.x example):

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

dicts = [{'a': 's1'}, {'a': 's2'}, {'a': 's2', 'b': 's3'}]

union = {k: sorted(set(map(itemgetter(1), items))) for k, items in
         groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in dicts)),
                 key=itemgetter(0))}

# union = {'a': ['s1', 's2'], 'b': ['s3']}
```

Comment: I would note that this is Python 2.x and include the import statements.